# Unexpected socket.getaddrinfo behavior in Python using SOCK_STREAM

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, getaddrinfo

- I'm busy trying to use `socket.getaddrinfo()` to resolve a domain name. When I pass in:

`host = 'www.google.com', port = 80, family = socket.AF_INET, type = 0, proto = 0, flags = 0`

I get a pair of socket infos like you'd expect, one with SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM (for UDP) and and the other with SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM (TCP).

- When I set proto to `socket.IPPROTO_TCP` I narrow it to only TCP as expected.
- However, when I use `proto = socket.SOCK_STREAM` (which shouldn't work) I get back a SocketKind.SOCK_RAW.
- Also, Python won't let me use `proto = socket.IPPROTO_RAW` - I get 'Bad hints'.

Any thoughts on what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

`socket.SOCK_STREAM` should be passed in the `type` field. Using it in the `proto` field probably has a very random effect, which is what you're seeing. Proto only takes the `IPPROTO` constants. For a raw socket, you should use `type = socket.SOCK_RAW`. I'm not sure `getaddrinfo` supports that though, it's mostly for TCP and UDP.

It's probably better to have some actual code in your questions. It's much easier to see what's going on then.